# Destroy function of kendo grid being called again and again

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which has a delete icon on every row. Now, the grid adds and updates data everytime I add something to it. It deletes rows just fine.But, after I have deleted the last row in the grid, it subsequently starts calling the destroy function everytime the page loads.So, it doesn't allow any data to be stored in the grid. Here is the code, please help me with this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ATMS.Data.DataAccess.DataEntities.Address>()
                .Name("gvPriorAddressList")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Template(@<text></text>).Width(30)
                   .ClientTemplate(@"<a class='k-button-icontext k-grid-delete' href='\#'><img alt='delete' src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/Layout/delete_icon.gif") + "'/></a>");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Address1).Width(170);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Address2).Width(170);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.City).Width(150);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.State).Width(120);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Zip).Title("Zip Code").Width(120); 
                    columns.Bound(p => p.AddressLinkID).Hidden(true);
                })
                .Navigatable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
                        .Editable(editable =>
                        {
                            editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom);
                        })
                .Events(e => e.Edit("onAddressGridEdit"))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(p => p.AddressId);
                            model.Field(p => p.LeadId).DefaultValue(Model);
                            model.Field(p => p.Address1);
                            model.Field(p => p.Address2);
                            model.Field(p => p.City);
                            model.Field(p => p.State);
                            model.Field(p => p.Zip);
                        })
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetAddress", "HomeLead", new { LeadId = Model }))
                .Create(create => create.Action("AddUpdateAddress", "HomeLead", new { LeadId = Model }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("AddUpdateAddress", "Homelead", new { LeadId = Model }))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAddress", "Homelead", new { LeadId = Model }))
                        )
                     )
```

Comment: Is it only doing multiple deletes after you have started to update/add new things? Or is it doing the multiple deletes from the initial load of data?

Comment: It starts to delete after I have deleted the last row in the grid. Then it simply doesn't allow to enter any new rows.
I enter one row and it calls the delete function to delete it.

Comment: What does your delete/update actions look like?

Comment: Updates can be done to the rows. Delete action is a gif icon that deletes the entire row from the grid. Then upon save, the "DeleteAddress" function is called that deletes the record from the table. 
There are two tables essentially and if the record is from the second table, it is not deleted, but its values are changed to NULL.

Comment: I understand what is going on with the delete function and that you are `queuing` up the deletes (which will fire as many times as you have requested to delete items) using the batch solution but what is being returned from your action? So my question is does the same behaviour occur when setting `.Batch(false)`?

Comment: What if you use this grid in isolation without any other code? If this is part of a bigger `control/feature set` then it is difficult to give you an answer based on one part of a potential bigger problem. typically with multiple requires being fired off like updates & creates it is usually the returning data not being set correctly for the grid to register the update has performed successfully.